# Can I inject css file directly into current active tab from my chrome extention's content.js when tab is loaded useng manifest-version-3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to add css file into current active tabe frome chrome extention's content.js file with out using background.js file.

here as currently I am injecting css from background.js like

```
    if (message.action === "injectCSS") {
        // Use chrome.scripting.insertCSS in the background script
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            const activeTab = tabs[0];
            chrome.scripting.insertCSS({`your text`
                target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
                files: ["popup.css"],`your text`
            });
        });
    }
```

So how can I do it in content.js directly to add css?

Comment: Create a `link` element with `elem.rel = 'stylesheet'` and `elem.href = chrome.runtime.getURL('file.css')`, add file.css to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/), reload the extension.